# How to open a Firefox using a certain profile if profile is not already running or else reuse it

Tags: macos, firefox

I open Firefox using the following command to open a new instance and using the profile "Profile_name"

```
   open -n -a Firefox.app --args -profile Profile_name -no-remote
```

But I may not know if this profile is already running so when I again use the same command to open Firefox it says "Only one instance can be open at a time"

So is there a command to start a new instance for the profile if it is not already running or else reuse the already running instance?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `-no-remote` command-line argument, which precisely tells your Firefox to not reuse an existing instance even if there is one?

Comment: Omitting of `-no-remote` does not work for me. If this option is not present and Firefox instance of another profile is already running, `-profile <profile-name>` option is ignored and window of running instance is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you just want a new blank, non-clashing, profile each time you run the command:

```
open -n -a Firefox.app --args -profile `mktemp -d /tmp/tmp-fx-profile.XXXX` -no-remote -new-instance
```